# How Exit Foreach statement from VB Macro Code?

Tags: excel, vba

Senario:
Hi I'm new to macro programming...I need to compare two columns from different work books and copying the non-matching values in one of the workbook.

Code:

```
For Each y In CompareRange     
         For Each x In Selection       
            If x <> y Then temp = y       
                    intRowPosition = intRowPosition + 1
                      Next x
                      Workbooks("junk").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & CStr(intRowPosition)).Value = temp
                      intRowPosition = intRowPosition - 5                           
              Next y
```

Issue:

In the Above code (if x <> y is false) i need the loop to move to Next Y,
Please let me know how I can get out from foreach loop.

Comment: Use `Exit For`.

Comment: @Daniel you ahould add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First option: if you want to execute what is after the X loop

```
For Each y In CompareRange     
    For Each x In Selection       
        If x <> y Then temp = y       
                intRowPosition = intRowPosition + 1
        Else
             Exit For
        End If
    Next x

    Workbooks("junk").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & CStr(intRowPosition)).Value = temp
    intRowPosition = intRowPosition - 5                           
Next y
```

Second Option: if you don't want to execute what is after the X loop.

```
Dim CanExecute as Boolean    

For Each y In CompareRange    
    CanExecute = True

    For Each x In Selection       
        If x <> y Then temp = y       
                intRowPosition = intRowPosition + 1
        Else
            CanExecute = False
        End If
    Next x

    If CanExecute Then
        Workbooks("junk").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & CStr(intRowPosition)).Value = temp
        'I'm not sure if this would be inside or outside the if, that's up to you.
        intRowPosition = intRowPosition - 5                           
    End If
Next y
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to specify a range.  This is one way.

```
 For Each y In Workbooks("junk").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B5:B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row     
     For Each x In Workbooks("junk").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C5:C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row            
        If x <> y Then temp = y       
        intRowPosition = intRowPosition + 1
     Next x
     Workbooks("junk").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & CStr(intRowPosition)).Value = temp
     intRowPosition = intRowPosition - 5                           
  Next y
```

Answer (score -2):

You could add a name into the name manager and then link it back into the macro like so, have a try and see if it works.

```
Dim CompareRange As Range
Set CompareRange = Range("compare_range")

For Each y In CompareRange
         For Each x In Selection
            If x <> y Then
            temp = y

                   intRowPosition = intRowPosition + 1
                      End If 'Added this in
                      Next x
                      Workbooks("junk1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & CStr(intRowPosition)).Value = temp
                      intRowPosition = intRowPosition - 5
              Next y
```